# How to ignore member in list-to-list mapping?

Tags: list, mapping, automapper, member

I'm using Automapper in a .NET Core Web Application. I'm trying to map a List to an other one. It doesn't ignore members that i select in `ForMember`, but when I map an object to an object it works fine!

Code:

```
var mapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(a =>
        {
            var b = a.CreateMap<SmsContact, SmsContactViewModel>()
                .IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter()
                .IgnoreAllSourcePropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter();
            
            b.ForMember(v => v.PhoneNumber, v => v.Ignore());
      
        });

        var destModel = _smsContactService.GetAll(a => true).ToList();

        var m=mapperConfig.CreateMapper().Map(editModel, destModel);
```